# IFs Statement in Excel Only Spitting out first criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

```
=IFS(
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=80, 8,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=70, 7,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=60, 6,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=50, 5,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=40, 4,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=30, 3,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=20, 2,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=10, 1,
    [@[Insurance Score]]>=0, 0
)
```

I am using this formula right now, however, Excel is spitting out an 8 in every single row, meaning the insurance score is over 80, which very few are.

I have tried to change the greater and less than signs around, mess with the data I am trying to group (ie: change the formatting), and rearrange the formula.

Comment: It would be best to create a table of reference, having lower and higher bound in two ranges with the adjacent column having required values, then it would be easier with `VLOOKUP()` or `XLOOKUP()` to perform an approximate match

Comment: Insurance score might be text so >=80 is TRUE. Also you could try =IF(A2>=80,8,FLOOR(A2,10)/10)

Comment: Your formula is supposed to be entered in the first cell of a column in the table and it will spill down.  It could be simplified with e.g. `=IF([@[Insurance Score]]>=80,8,INT([@[Insurance Score]]/10))`. More importantly, you're describing the behavior occurring when the numbers in the column are text. In that case, you should replace `[@[Insurance Score]]` with `Value([@[Insurance Score]])`.

Comment: user11222393 & VBasic2008 sir, if the `[@[Insurance Score]]` score is formatted as text then also it would return all the values as `8` with formula suggested by you both since it is getting the first argument as `TRUE` it wont go for the `FALSE` argument any further and it wont work as it intended to be as for string manipulation OP needs to add a double unary or multiply by 1 or divide by 1 or add 0 to the insurance score that said the formula will be `=IF(--[@[Insurance Score]]>=80,8,FLOOR(--[@[Insurance Score]],10)/10)` or `=IF(--[@[Insurance Score]]>=80,8,INT([@[Insurance Score]]/10))`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this formula:

```
=MIN(FLOOR(C5/10;1);8)
```

It has following results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented above it is relatively easy to do using a `Table Reference` however let me show you what you should do with your existing formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

```
=IFS(
     [@[Insurance Score]]>=80, 8,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=70,[@[Insurance Score]]<80), 7,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=60,[@[Insurance Score]]<70), 6,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=50,[@[Insurance Score]]<60), 5,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=40,[@[Insurance Score]]<50), 4,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=30,[@[Insurance Score]]<40), 3,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=20,[@[Insurance Score]]<30), 2,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=10,[@[Insurance Score]]<20), 1,
     AND([@[Insurance Score]]>=0,[@[Insurance Score]]<10), 0)
```

---

If you use your existing formula in this way it would work, however it would better if you start with the lower end values first, like as below,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=IFS(
     [@[Insurance Score]]<10, 0,
     [@[Insurance Score]]<20, 1,
     [@[Insurance Score]]<30, 2,
     [@[Insurance Score]]<40, 3,
     [@[Insurance Score]]<50, 4,
     [@[Insurance Score]]<60, 5,
     [@[Insurance Score]]<70, 6,
     [@[Insurance Score]]<80, 7,
     [@[Insurance Score]]>=80, 8)
```

---

Now try using <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> or <kbd>LOOKUP()</kbd> or <kbd>VLOOKUP()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LOOKUP([@[Insurance Score]],$A$2:$C$10)
```

---

Or,

[image]

```
=XLOOKUP([@[Insurance Score]],Lower,Val,,-1)
```

---

Or,

```
=VLOOKUP([@[Insurance Score]],$A$2:$C$10,3,1)
```

---

Please refer how much easy and simpler it is when using a reference table to lookup and use any one of the lookup function to do an approximate match.

---

However, if the cells are formatted as text, then simply add a double unary(forces the string manipulation to be a number) before the insurance score. then your existing formula would work as intended.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=IFS(
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=80, 8,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=70, 7,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=60, 6,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=50, 5,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=40, 4,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=30, 3,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=20, 2,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=10, 1,
    --[@[Insurance Score]]>=0, 0
)
```

---